# basic sample google-app-engine project not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to python and google-app-engine programming.
I just followed the sample project with this url : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=jWRtX8vs_cM"
I installed python 2.7.12 and followed the just the same course of this video.
At the last part of the process I could not get the result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hflZJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESBoL.png)

I wrote the commands according to the video sample(first Pic), but there are no errors and no actions:
if the process works good, it must be like the second picture and I have to check the result in Web browser with localhost:8000\instances:
I searched the solution of this project here, but could not get yet.
If helps me, I really appreciate that. Thanks...

"test.py"

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

   def get(self):
       self.response.write("Hello World")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(('/',MainPage),], debug=True)
```

"app.yaml"

```
runtime: python37

api_version:1

threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url:/

  script:test.app
```

Comment: always put text instead of images.

Comment: Thanks! help me with this project please!

Answer (score 0):

The `webapp2` framework is only available in the `python27` runtime, not `python37`. You'll either need to downgrade to the first-generation Python 2.7 runtime, or (the better option) stay on Python 3.7 and use a modern framework.

The equivalent in Flask would be:

`app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.0.2
```

`main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'
```

See "[Quickstart for Python 3 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart)" for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I said Now  I installed python 2.7.12.  Do I have to install more earlier version of Python ?  First generations are meaning around 2.7.1-5?  In this video sample they installed 2.7.12 and executed successfully. How can I understand this?

Comment: "First generation" meaning Python 2, second generation meaning Python 3. If you want to stick with Python 2, you must remove the `runtime: python37` line from your `app.yaml`, but it's not recommended, [Python 2 will reach end-of-life at the end of this year](https://pythonclock.org/)